# PHP preg_match and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, string

I am fairly new to PHP and regular expressions, after reading i have got this far trying to understand how to extract correct info,

Sample data

```
2011/09/20  00:57       367,044,608 S1E04 - Cancer Man.avi
2012/03/12  03:01       366,991,496 Family Guy - S09E01 - And Then There Were Fewer.avi
2012/03/25  00:27        53,560,510 Avatar- The Legend of Korra S01E01.avi
```

What i would like to extract is the Date, File size and name of the file, remembering that the file can start with basically anything. and file size changes all the time.

What i have currently.

```
$dateModifyed = substr($file, 0, 10); 
$fileSize = preg_match('[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*/s[0-9]*:[0-9]*/s*', $file, $match)
$FileName =
```

Full code i am working on

```
function recursivePrint($folder, $subFolders, $Jsoncounter) {
$f = fopen("file.json", "a");

echo '{ "id" : "' . $GLOBALS['Jsoncounter'] . '", parent" : "' . "#" . '", Text" : "' . $folder . '" },' . "\n";
$PrintString = '{ "id" : "' . $GLOBALS['Jsoncounter'] . '", parent" : "' . "#" . '", Text" : "' . $folder . '" },' . "\n";
fwrite($f, $PrintString);
$foldercount = $GLOBALS['Jsoncounter'];
$GLOBALS['Jsoncounter']++;
foreach($subFolders->files as $file) {


    preg_match('/^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2})\s+([\d,]+)\s+(.*)$/', $file, $match);
    $dateModified = $match[1];
    $fileSize = str_replace(',', '', $match[2]);
    $fileName = $match[3];
    echo $dateModified . $fileSize . $fileName;


    echo '{ "id" : "' . $GLOBALS['Jsoncounter'] . '", parent" : "' . $foldercount . '", Text" : "' . $file . '" },';
    $PrintString ='{ "id" : "' . $GLOBALS['Jsoncounter'] . '", parent" : "' . $foldercount . '", Text" : "' . $file . '" },';
    fwrite($f, $PrintString);
    $GLOBALS['Jsoncounter']++;
}

foreach($subFolders->folders as $folder => $subSubFolders) {
    recursivePrint($folder, $subSubFolders, $Jsoncounter);
}
fclose($f);
```

}

Any help extracting the correct numbers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How is your data accessible in your PHP file? Is it saved in a variable? Please post complete relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have added the full function i am working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your regex:

```
preg_match('[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*/s[0-9]*:[0-9]*/s*', $file, $match)
            ^--missing delimiter ^            ^-- asterisk instead of plus
                                 |--literal s instead of \s
```

and of course you haven't used [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) or [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and the regex isn't finished yet.

Try the following:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%^                     # Start of line
    ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)  # Date (group 1)
    \s+                     # Whitespace
    ([0-9]+:[0-9]+)         # Time (group 2)
    \s+                     # Whitespace
    ([0-9,]+)               # File size (group 3)
    \s+                     # Whitespace
    (.*)                    # Rest of the line%mx', 
    $file, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
    for ($backrefi = 0; $backrefi < count($result[$matchi]); $backrefi++) {
        # Matched text = $result[$matchi][$backrefi];
```

so for example `$result[0][1]` will contain `2011/09/20`, and `$result[2][4]` will contain `Avatar- The Legend of Korra S01E01.avi` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *capture groups* to get the parts of the string that are matched by different parts of the regular expression. Capture groups use parentheses around portions of the regexp.

```
preg_match('#^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2})\s+([\d,]+)\s+(.*)$#', $string, $match);
$dateModified = $match[1];
$fileSize = str_replace(',', '', $match[2]);
$fileName = $match[3];
```

Other problems in your regexp:

- You left out the delimiters at the beginning and end.
- You used `/s` instead of `\s` for whitespace characters.

There's a tutorial on regular expressions at [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Thanks for that, when using the code above, I am getting a error of "( ! ) Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in C:\wamp\www\DataConverter1.2.php on line 75" , must be a issue in the regular expression, is there a method of working out what would be the cause?

Comment: Forgot that there were literal `/` characters in the regular expression, so I needed to escape them or use a different delimiter around the RE. I've changed the delimiter to `#`.